# Access Jboss war deployment over internet

Tags: jboss

I have Jboss application server 7 running in a windows 2008 server. I have a war file that I’ve deployed to Jboss that contains a webpage. I can access this webpage ,locally , by using the url

```
http://localhost:8080/test/page1.jsf.
```

However I can’t access it externally

```
http://<Ipaddress>:8080/test/page1.jsf
```

does not work. 
I have  my Jboss folder in my intepub/root folder, where I can access webpages and text files through my url

```
http://<Ipaddress>:8080/<documentname>
```

What steps do I have to take to be able to access content in my war file.
My server is accepting http on 8080, but does Jboss need to be configured in some way?
This is very confusing as I expected this to just happen automatically and not be this much of an issue

Edit

I tried editing my standalone.xml with the following and it still isn't working.

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
      <any-ipv4-address/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you start the JBoss service. Make sure you always provide the IP of your server in order to access from anywhere using the `-b <ip>` command when starting the server: `#> start.bat -b 127.0.0.1`. Refer to [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Command+line+parameters) for more options when starting JBoss service.

Comment: I have done this before but it hasnt helped. For example this is from my standalone.xml above in the original post.